# How to handle AssertionError in Python and find out which line or statement it occurred on?

Tags: python, assert

I want to handle `AssertionError`s both to hide unnecessary parts of the stack trace from the user and to print a message as to why the error occurred and what the user should do about it.

**Is there any way to find out on which line or statement the `assert` failed within the `except` block?**

```
try:
    assert True
    assert 7 == 7
    assert 1 == 2
    # many more statements like this
except AssertionError:
    print 'Houston, we have a problem.'
    print
    print 'An error occurred on line ???? in statement ???'
    exit(1)
```

I don't want to have to add this to every assert statement:

```
assert 7 == 7, "7 == 7"
```

because it repeats information.

Comment: Two issues.  First, if you are having trouble identifying where the exception is happening in your `try..except`, that's a sign your `try..except` block is too big.  Second, the kind of thing meant to be caught by `assert` isn't something the user should ever see.  If they see an `AssertionError`, the proper course of action is for them to contact the programmer and say "WTF?!".

Comment: @John Y, you seem confused.  You're saying `AssertionError`s shouldn't be seen by the user, and then what the user should do when he sees one.  It can't be both!

Comment: BTW: Asserts should be about the structure of your code, that is, an assert should fail only if you have a bug in your software.  They should not be used to check user input.  You might consider using a different exception for this application.

Comment: @NedBatchelder Thanks, you are correct.  I may reconsider using asserts here, but the procedure for getting the line code will still be useful.

Comment: @NedBatchelder Why should asserts not be used for user input validation? What alternatives are recommended?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Use the [traceback](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html) module:

```
import sys
import traceback

try:
    assert True
    assert 7 == 7
    assert 1 == 2
    # many more statements like this
except AssertionError:
    _, _, tb = sys.exc_info()
    traceback.print_tb(tb) # Fixed format
    tb_info = traceback.extract_tb(tb)
    filename, line, func, text = tb_info[-1]

    print('An error occurred on line {} in statement {}'.format(line, text))
    exit(1)
```

Comment: How do I get the actual value instead of the line vars? e.g  assert a == b I want to show the values of a and b. I tried sys.exc_info()[1] but it's empty

Comment: @0x2bad Try `assert a == b, (a, b)`, which will give you the values in `sys.exc_info()[1].args[0]` – or easier, name the AssertionError you catch `ae`, then it's in `ae.args[0]`.
You can also create a helper method which does the actual assertion. This is what [`unittest.TestCase.assertEqual`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual) does.

Comment: I took the nose approach here https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/blob/7c26ad1e6b7d308cafa328ad34736d34028c122a/nose/inspector.py#L18 to get the exact value. So I can keep the exception message meaning full

Answer (score 52):

The traceback module and sys.exc_info are overkill for tracking down the source of an exception. That's all in the default traceback. So instead of calling exit(1) just re-raise:

```
try:
    assert "birthday cake" == "ice cream cake", "Should've asked for pie"
except AssertionError:
    print 'Houston, we have a problem.'
    raise
```

Which gives the following output that includes the offending statement and line number:

```
Houston, we have a problem.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/poop.py", line 2, in <module>
    assert "birthday cake" == "ice cream cake", "Should've asked for pie"
AssertionError: Should've asked for pie
```

Similarly the  logging module makes it easy to log a traceback for any exception (including those which are caught and never re-raised):

```
import logging

try:
    assert False == True 
except AssertionError:
    logging.error("Nothing is real but I can't quit...", exc_info=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way would be:

```
try:
    assert True, 'first'
    assert 7 == 7, 'second'
    assert 1 == 2, 'third'
    # many more statements like this
except AssertionError as e:
    print(f'Assertion failed at the {str(e)} line')
    exit(1)
```