# raise Assertionerror vs. assert python

Tags: python, error-handling, assert

What are the big differences between `raise AssertionError` and `assert` to build in a "fault"? What are the effects on the code? And is one or the other more pythonic in a way?

The reason for my question is because I am learning to program. Right now we have an exercise where for example when `x != 0` we need to get an `AssertionError` "false".

I looked this up online, where I found the following code:

```py
if x != 0:
    raise AssertionError ("false")
```

But my teachers also use the following a lot:

```py
assert x == 0,"fout"
```

What are the (dis)advantages of each approach?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question a bit? Generally, assertions are for testing your code and finding bugs. `assert` statements can be ignored with compiler flags.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i explained it a bit more. Hope this helps :)

Comment: As juanpa explained, the `assert` statement is generally for unit-testing or finding issues during the development process. This does not mean you will necessarily see the error. On the other hand, raising an `AssertionError` means that the error will be raised by the code, and that any calling processes can deal with this error as needed.

Comment: This may be useful as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182944/difference-between-raise-try-and-assert

Comment: @Brandon Barney. So if I got this correct you use assert during development but then for the finished program you use Assertionerror.  Or not quite ? And can you give an example of not seeing an error ? I don't quite see how that can happen ..

Answer (score 22):

Those two code examples are equivalent, with the exception that `assert` statements can be globally disabled with the `-O` command-line flag.

Comment: This command-line flag. Is this something I manually enter? (I have never heard of this before and a first google round hasn't bin helpful)

Comment: When you run your code by typing `python myscript.py`, you can instead type `python -O myscript.py`.  (If you run code from an IDE instead of the command-line, your IDE probably has an option somewhere to achieve the same effect.)

Comment: It can also make a difference to [`pylint`](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/2908).