# Why does 'raised Error' work, but 'assert' doesn't?

Tags: python, assert, raiseerror

There is a difference when I use assert and raised ValuError, why?

The following code, only stop my script when I use `raise ValueError`, `assert` does not work.

```
assert (len(dictA) != len(dictB)), 'Your have an .... error'

if len(dictA) != len(dictB):
    raise ValueError('Your have an ... error')
```

Comment: Note also that this isn't best practice usage of assert, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/945135/3001761

Answer (score 3):

You need to use

```
assert (len(dictA) == len(dictB))
```

The error is thrown when the condition evaluates to False.

Comment: Thank you Felipe. Do you mind to explain which one (assert or valueerror) is better to use in this situation?

Comment: Depends on your use case. Check the accepted answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182944/difference-between-raise-try-and-assert/40183195