# What is difference between Python try and assert?

Tags: python-3.x, exception

I am new to Python and would like to know what is the difference between Try and assert and situations where each one is more suitable. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the use of "assert" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142418/what-is-the-use-of-assert-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between Raise Try and Assert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182944/difference-between-raise-try-and-assert)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

You can read the documentation for `try` here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

You can read the documentation for `assert` here:
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html

Essentially, `try` means try the following block of code, and if there is an error, it is handled in the `except` part.

For example:

```
try:
   print(1/0) #a division by 0, should raise an error.
except ZeroDivisionError:
   print("You tried to divide by zero!")
```

So instead of the program crashing, it prints "you tried to divide by zero" instead.

`assert` means "make sure the following is true".

So imagine if we had a function that did division, and we wanted to make sure that the denominator was never zero, we could do:

```
def divide(a, b):
    assert b != 0
    return a/b
```

This is a pretty bad example, but basically what's happening here is that if b is ever equal to 0, the assertion raises an exception, which prevents the program from continuing unless that exception is handled.