# In python assert, how to print the condition when the assertion failed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, assert

In Python, I can do:

```
assert result==100, "result should be 100"
```

but this is redundant since I have to type the condition twice.

Is there a way to tell Python to automatically show the condition when the assertion fails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With pure Python, you can't reproduce the condition of the assertion automatically easily. The [**pytest**](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) testing framework does exactly what you want, but the implementation for this magic is everything [but trivial](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/master/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py). In short, **pytest** [rewrites the code of your assertions](http://pybites.blogspot.de/2011/07/behind-scenes-of-pytests-new-assertion.html) to  complex code to capture the information needed to generate the desired error message.

Answer (score 8):

**From Jupyter notebook**

This happens with traceback. For example:

```
x = 2
assert x < 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-0662b7144a79> in <module>()
      1 x = 2
----> 2 assert x < 1

AssertionError:
```

However, it is good practice to humanize (i.e. explain in words) why this error occurs. Often, I use it to feed back useful information. For example:

```
x = 2
assert x < 1, "Number is not less than 1: {0}".format(x)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-bd4b9b15ccc2> in <module>()
      1 x = 2
----> 2 assert x < 1, "Number is not less than 1: {0}".format(x)

AssertionError: Number is not less than 1: 2
```

**From command line**

This *still* happens with traceback. For example:

```
H:\>python assert.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "assert.py", line 1, in <module>
    assert 2 < 1
AssertionError
```

**Solution for all environments**

Use the [traceback](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html) module. For details, see answer at [How to handle AssertionError in Python and find out which line or statement it occurred on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587223/how-to-handle-assertionerror-in-python-and-find-out-which-line-or-statement-it-o)

Comment: The question seems to be whether this *humanization* can be done automatically.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis Apologies I think you're right, it's only in the interpreter that it fails

Comment: @jp_data_analysis Very true. Let's not call it *humanization* then XD

Comment: From your answer it is not very clear to me which snippet corresponds to `assert.py`. Could you clarify?

Comment: @jp_data_analysis The behavior you are describing cannot be trusted though. Running this code in different places produces different results. Running it on a Python shell for example behaves differently; it does not provide any information regarding the assertion that failed.

Answer (score 0):

[assertpy](https://github.com/assertpy/assertpy#soft-assertions) is a small nice package which prints out useful error message out of the box:

```py
>>> assert_that('foo').is_equal_to('bar')

Expected <foo> to be equal to <bar>, but was not.
```